# How to Sign up for Force Platform User Licence

Tags: force

When I hit the Force.com URL and sign up for a 30 day trial - I was given a Salesforce user licence subscription.

However, I only wanted a Force platform user licence. How do I ensure that I have a Force user licence and NOT a Salesforce licence. This is so I can trial in the correct Force platform environment with its different limits etc

What is the correct way to obtain a trial Force platform user subscription ?

Answer (score 0):

If you're developing a package or app for Salesforce, you should enroll in the partner program. This will allow you to spin up "Partner Development Environment"s through the Environment Hub. These PDEs come with many of every license type, so you can create users and log into the environment as all the different user types you need to support.

Comment: Thanks @Christian-Carter for that. However, I wanted to know how I can select Force.com user licences in production environment (Force.com Enterprise App ) and not in development environment.

Comment: Hey @TickleMe, from the Environment Hub you can also spin up a "Partner Demo Org" which is a true EE production Environment, but with all the different license types too.